# How do I install pandas on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, software-installation, pip

I'm trying to install Python Pandas on my Raspi and I'm finding strange errors.

```
~ $ pip install pandas
Downloading/unpacking pandas
Downloading pandas-0.13.1.tar.gz (6.1Mb): 6.1Mb downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package pandas

warning: no files found matching 'README.rst'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere in distribution
....
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:13:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function âkh_del_pymapâ:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:38:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function âkh_del_pysetâ:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:44:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h: In function âkh_del_strboxâ:
pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:49:1: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

and then more <strike>errors</strike> warnings for a long time. It never actually fails, but doesn't complete either in over half an hour. What is going on here and how do I fix it?

**Edited to add**

I have tried the alternative route of `sudo apt-get install python-pandas` which does install `pandas` but it's only version 0.8 rather than 0.13. Trying to follow up with `sudo pip install pandas --upgrade` gives the same results as above.

Comment: what errors?? lines starting with word 'warning' are warnings, ignore them.

Comment: It's more the fact that the installation doesn't finish that worried me. This was just the start of a long dump of warnings. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Are you sure it's broken? Pandas relies on numpy which can take an extremely long time to build, even on a very fast desktop machine. Did this ever complete? I'm considering using pandas for a project on my Pi so I'm curious if you had luck with this or gave up.

Comment: Yes, it did work. It took a long time to build but got there in the end and has been working fine ever since.

Comment: Facing the exact same problem myself now, how long did it take in the end @JamieBull ?

Comment: I don't recall exactly. A couple of hours I think.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Going back to basics, I looked at the [installation page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html) for `pandas` and found that `pip install pandas` isn't the recommended route on `linux` systems.

`sudo apt-get install python-pandas` did the trick.

Comment: This works but installs pandas 0.14.1 (old) when using Raspbian Jessie. Here is an answer that gives two other options. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42682928/raspberry-pi-python-install-pandas-on-python-3-5-2

Comment: This installs on the default Python 2, for Python 3 use `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: I just tried this on my Pi4B and it seems to have installed v 0.23.3

Answer (score 9):

`sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` works on the Raspberry Pi4 and the pandas version is `0.23.3`.

Comment: That is the only way I could install on a Pi3B+

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works but I then faced issues getting pandas into the virtualenv that I had created. Copying this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466663/memory-error-while-using-pip-install-matplotlib

from a related matplotlib issue fixed my situation on the latest raspbian install.

Solution: pip --no-cache-dir install pandas

Answer (score 0):

Personally I create a virtual environment and install `pandas` through `pip` (the relevant dependencies such as `numpy` will be installed along the way)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo pip3 install pandas` worked for mine

Comment: `pip3` is for Python3 whereas the OP was using `pip`, which means he's using Python 2. Therefore, he should try `sudo pip install pandas` instead of using `pip3`, because Python 2 won't be able to find modules installed using `pip3`.

Comment: @user96931 not necessarily so. This is a pretty old question but on a current system `python` might (and imho should) link to Python 3 and `pip` links to `pip3`.

Comment: It's better to be explicit than risk error through ambiguity.